# next run time missed by some seconds in job scheduling in apscheuler

Tags: python, apscheduler

i have a function to execute cron job as

```
def add_config_job(sched, job):

    module = JOB_METHODS.get(job["type"])
    if module is None:
        logging.warn("job type %r not supported", job["type"])
        return

    func = module.cron_job
    args = (job,)
    name = "%s__%s" % (job["name"], job["id"])
    start_date = job.get("start_date")
    run_at = job["run_at"]

    if isinstance(job["run_at"], dict):
        sched.add_cron_job(func, args=args, name=name, start_date=start_date,
                           **run_at)
    elif isinstance(job["run_at"], basestring):
        sched.add_date_job(func, args=args, name=name, date=run_at)
    else:
        logging.warn("unsupported 'run_at' type (%s given)", run_at)
```

and I get the error as missed job by some seconds as

```
2015-05-14_00:00:02.76629 WARNING: Run time of job "Daily VPN Connexion__1 (trigger: cron[day='*', hour='0', minute='0', second='0'], next run at: 2015-05-14 00:00:00)" was missed by 0:00:02.493426
2015-05-14_00:00:02.79309 WARNING: Run time of job "Daily Report VPN Connection ALIGRO__1 (trigger: cron[day='*', hour='0', minute='0', second='0'], next run at: 2015-05-14 00:00:00)" was missed by 0:00:02.777450
```

what is the cause of this misfiring of the job? how can we avoid it?
in some pages I found to increase the  misfire_grace_time from the default of 1 second. shouldn't be the scheduler schedule in proper time without missing it?

Comment: did you get solution for this? 'misfire_grace_time' also not working.

Answer (score 17):

It seems to be that your process is too busy to start the jobs in a timely manner. The `misfire_grace_time` option is there to prevent jobs from firing after they're no longer relevant. If something needs to happen at some exact time and it's delayed too much, it shouldn't happen at all. Increasing `misfire_grace_time` is the solution if this is happening and you don't care about accuracy so much.

Comment: what can be the cause of process too busy? Is it he maximum number of jobs scheduled causes the process too busy. Is this the drawback of the apschedular library? or can we change our code to fix it apart from misfire_grace_time

Comment: Gronholm what about using  max_instances

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific than "not working".